# Separating octets in a hex string in MatLab

Tags: string, matlab, hex

I have a long string of hex values which at some point lost its formatting and now looks like  a single *long* string, such as:

```
Str1=
    001ba212c6b4001f162e9ab208004500003f1bdc40008011322ea9fe58a6a9fe0001c350c350002b0345001ba212c6b400007100be002c151300be0000000108000b000133ffffffffffffffff
```

I want to separate the octets. It would be great to get a string vector with the octets divided like so:

```
Str2=
    00 1b a2 12 ... 00 00 00
```

The most intuitive approach I tried manages to separate the single characters but instead of a single hex value yields one row vector with two chars back:

```
for i=2:2:length(Str1)       
    Str2(i/2,1)=Str1(i-1);       
    Str2(i/2,2)=Str1(i);    
end
```

The output is:

```
Str2=
    00
    1b
    a2
    12 
    ..
```

which is not so bad, but could be better.  Any ideas or fancy functions I am not aware of?

Comment: What you are referring to as a "one row vector with two chars" is actually an N by 2 array. Matlab stores one character per array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to reshape the string into a two-column matrix of chars:

```
Str2 = reshape(Str1, 2, [])';
```

If you want to delimit octet strings with spaces, you can use `sprintf` instead:

```
Str2 = [sprintf('%c%c ', Str1(1:end - 2)), Str1(end - 1:end)];
```

`sprintf` reads `Str1`, two chars at a time, and adds interleaving spaces. Since the last two chars don't need a trailing space, they are concatenated separately.